# Importing a file and store in an array (Java)

Tags: java

Here's the setup I have so far, I need to figure out how to import the student's name, ID and whether they are taking the course for a grade from an external file.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Roster {
private String students[]; //A 1D array of Students
private int size; //The number of Students in the class
private double average; //The class grade average
private int numTests;
private int numProgs;
private int percentTests;
private int percentProgs;


//setters
public void setStudents (String[] args) throws IOException { // Read in the Student information from an external file
    FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
    Scanner s = null;

    fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
    s = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
    this.setSize(s.nextInt());
    this.setNumTests(s.nextInt());
    this.setNumProgs(s.nextInt());
    this.setPercentTests(s.nextInt());
    this.setPercentProgs(s.nextInt());

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        //read in the students name, id and whether or not the class is pass/fail

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        //read in 8 test/progs values
    }
```

Here is an example file:

```
12
3
5
55
45
Joe Smith
12345678
T
Mary Jones
23456789
T
Homer Simpson
98725432
F
Barney Fife
53245212
T
Sonic Pi
19834567
T
Pac Man
43256745
T
Clara Barton
34526578
T
Thomas Jefferson
37623482
T
Donald Trump
87623456
T
Barack Obama
76543210
T
Caesar Augustus
87236510
F
Peter Pan
65429000
T
87 83 75 89 75 97 98 60
77 72 89 74 99 84 78 65
82 92 72 85 95 69 89 95
65 82 79 87 86 0 60 90
75 92 89 97 83 68 94 92
92 96 95 100 100 95 98 99
91 90 86 96 90 85 82 90
100 100 96 100 90 95 97 99
```

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!